# Center logo icon in the Bootstrap collapsed menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The first image is what the menu looks like on a full-size browser window.

[Full-size menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR11Q.png)

The menu uses Bootstrap so when the window is narrower than a certain width, the little menu button comes up and you use that to open the menu.  However, when the menu is opened in the small window, I want the logo to be aligned vertically on the same axis as the menu items and also horizontally with the open menu button.

[Small window menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stlv7.png)

I tried giving the whole menu bar a width of 100% and centering the logo using `margin: 0 auto` but that didn't work. Using `position:absolute` for the menu button moved my button right in the middle, over the logo.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to transform it and aboslut:

`.navbar-brand {
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;}`

Comment: That works, but it takes my logo out of the menu bar. What could I do to fix that apart from `top = - 10px` let's say?

Comment: Add the logo into a container

Comment: that does not work for me, still leaves it out like this http://i64.tinypic.com/2m4dbir.png

Comment: Add a margin to the top or bottom